# ¿crear menus de ayuda cuando se abre app por primera vez?

Tags: android, android-studio

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta pregunta es demasiado básica y presenta problemas de formato y contenido. Comprendo que la idea principal está en el título, pero deberías incluir más y mejor información en el cuerpo (que es donde debería ir la parte importante): qué es lo que estás intentando lograr, que has intentado hasta el momento, qué restricciones tienes (si alguna)... tal y como está la pregunta ahora es demasiado amplia y es bastante subjetiva/basada en opiniones (puedes tener tantas recomendaciones como programadores)

Answer (score 1):

Bueno en este caso yo opte por usar una de las librerías que puedes encontrar en Github, sin duda realizan el trabajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://github.com/Cleveroad/SlidingTutorial-Android

https://github.com/faruktoptas/FancyShowCaseView

https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias librerías a tu disposición, todo depende la complejidad que quieras, si solo es mostrar titulo descripción o bien hacer un tutorial de uso y detectar si el usuario pulsa o entra el contenido para el siguiente punto etc...

**Librería FancyShowCaseView**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Descargar: https://github.com/faruktoptas/FancyShowCaseView

**Librería Material Tap Target Prompt**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Descargar: https://github.com/sjwall/MaterialTapTargetPrompt
Otra similar a la última: https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView

**Librería HintCase**

Para algo más personalizado
descargar: https://github.com/Nescafemix/hintcase

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un archivo XML en el que guardes si ya el usuario a entrado en la aplicacion y si no es asi que muestre el menu de ayuda y que guarde un valor en el XML para que no lo vuelva a presentar.